# Hold Button On Red5Phone

Tags: linux, asterisk, red5

I have configured Red5Phone on Red5 Server. I am able to connect to Asterisk Server its working fine. I have used Flex as a client.  Red5 and Asterisk are on the same server.

Now I want a implement a hold button, can anyone please guide me.

I am new to asterisk, how do I begin?

Do I directly need to call any asterisk function or does red5phone already has that function.

Comment: What does the manual say? This seems to be a pretty application specific question to ask here.

Comment: there is no manual for red5phone , i tried googling but havent found solution thanks for your responde.

Comment: This seems like it might be better off on SO, given that Sunil would have to code this functionality. It's an open-source SIP phone that runs in Flash, according to it's Google Code homepage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement hold button in flash part (use transfer button as example)
2. Call hold function from flash       (same as transfer button calls transfer method on server)
3. Implement hold function at server   (also you can start by copying server transfer)